# Adding sass folder to codeigniter public folder

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, sass, codeigniter-3

I have a codeigniter application where I am trying to implement the design I have currently implemented the design but some of the functionality is not working due to the sass not getting called I was wondering if anyone knows where I should be placing the sass folder and or if I should be altering the css files to call the sass.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

My call to the css is as follows:

```
   <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jqvmap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/css/components-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/global/css/plugins-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/layouts/layout4/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/layouts/layout4/css/themes/light.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>public/assets/layouts/layout4/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type=
```

I also have the sass just placed in the `public/assets` folder.

Comment: The SASS files do not get "called". They are used to compile CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should not be calling the SASS file. Instead app should call the CSS - compiled from the SASS.

> I was wondering if anyone knows where I should be placing the sass
>   folder and or if I should be altering the css files to call the sass.

You can actually place it on any folder and when compiled will be placed in your assets folder.